# C# Server receive command from Node.js Client

Tags: c#, node.js

I'm trying to create a C# Server and I want to communicate with node.js client, and here is my simple C# code and Node.js

C#

```
private System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream _controlStream;
private System.IO.StreamReader _controlReader;
private System.IO.StreamWriter _controlWriter;

public void HandleClient(object obj)
{
        _remoteEndPoint = (System.Net.IPEndPoint)_controlClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint;

        clientIP = remoteEndPoint.Address.ToString();

        controlStream = controlClient.GetStream();


        controlReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(controlClient.GetStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
        _controlWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(controlStream);
        Console.WriteLine(controlReader.ReadLine());


        _controlWriter.WriteLine("220 Service Ready.");
        _controlWriter.Flush();
 }
```

Node.js Client

```
var net = require('net');
var client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(8591, "127.0.0.1", function(){
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('Hello C# Server I am Node.js');
});

client.on('data', function(data){
    console.log("Receive:" + data);
});
client.on('error', function(err){
    console.log('err');
    console.log(err);
});
client.on('close', function(){
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

And here is my question, _controlReader.ReadLine() doesn't work

_controlReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(_controlClient.GetStream(), Encoding.UTF8);

Console.WriteLine(_controlReader.ReadLine());  => here my code doesn't work

The C# Server can execute, but when the server receives the client request and execute on Console.WriteLine(_controlReader.ReadLine()), the program doesn't work.

Do not show on C# Server Console.

I want to know why it doesn't work, or what should I do. Thanks

Comment: "here my code doesn't working" doesn't give us any details of what you actually see. Is it throwing an exception? Failing to compile? Just not printing anything? Printing the wrong thing? What's the type of `_controlClient`? If you could provide a [mcve] rather than just a snippet that would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Does `client.write('Hello C# Server I am Node.js');` terminate the string with a newline? If not, how can `StreamReader` read a line?

Comment: Yes, I expect this text will be sent to the server, and then the server will display this text.
But on the server side Console.WriteLine(controlStream.ReadLine()); After executing this code, no further steps are performed.

Comment: [ReadLine docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx): "A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n"). The string that is returned does not contain the terminating carriage return or line feed. The returned value is null if the end of the input stream is reached." - I reiterate my question: does `client.write(...)` termiante the string with a newline?

Comment: I add \n on the node.js and the program work well.

client.write('Hello C# Server I am Node.js\n');

So if i want to use ReadLine() my message always need to use \n as a end point? Or what else can i do

Comment: I don't have time to add a full answer now, but you could read the bytes and convert them back to a string. Note that not all of your string will necessarily arrive in a single packet, so it might be helpful to prefix it with a string length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ReadLine` method is waiting for the line to be terminated. This would be indicated by either:

- The stream being closed
- A line break in the stream

Neither of those is taking place in your sample code.

While line-oriented protocols like this can work and are easy to work with interactively, they make it hard to do things like embedding new lines... and the server doesn't know how much it needs to read until it sees the line break, which can be inefficient.

One very common approach to fixing this is to have a message-oriented protocol, where each message consists of a length (e.g. always written as 4 bytes, assuming you never need more than that) and then the body of the message. In your case the body of the message could just be a string, but equally you could add more structure.

The client would need to construct a message, send its length in bytes and then send the message data. This does have the downside of needing to know the length before you start sending the data, which isn't great for streaming a large message, for example, but in many cases it works well.

The server processing would then consist of:

- Reading the first four bytes and converting that back into an integer (the length)
- Allocating a buffer of that size
- Reading from the stream until it's filled the buffer
- Parsing the buffer (e.g. with `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)`

This is all significantly more work than just a line-oriented protocol, but it's generally more robust.

If you're really just experimenting, you may want to stick with a line-oriented protocol and make sure you put a line break at the end of each client message. If you're starting a full production service, you probably want to take a step back and think more carefully about the overall protocol you want to support.